# What is this plant & it looks like USA tree " Carya ovata"?

Tags: species-identification, trees

I saw this tree in India. It was so fascinating because its leaf looks like *Carya ovata*, which only grows in the USA & Canada according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carya_ovata):

> *Carya ovata*, the shagbark hickory, is a common hickory in the **Eastern United States and southeast Canada**.

Is it really *Carya ovata* or something else?

[image]

Comment: This looks nothing like *Carya ovata*.

Comment: Also, please add close-ups of the leaves, (supposed leaflets) and trunk if possible for a better chance at a correct ID

Comment: Are the branches opposite or alternate?